# OpenGL: When applying my own lookAt function the screen is blank

Tags: c, opengl, glm-math

I'm writing my own version of gluLookAt. I believe I have the correct implementation however, often the matrix that gets returned is full of nan's.

Here is my function:

```
mat4 look_at(vec4 eye, vec4 at, vec4 up)
{
  vec4 vpn = vec4_sub(eye, at);
  vec4 n = vec4_norm(vpn);
  vec4 u = vec4_norm(vec4_cross(up, n));
  vec4 v = vec4_norm(vec4_cross(n, u));
  vec4 p = { eye.x, eye.y, eye.z, 1 };

  mat4 m;
  m.x.x = u.x; m.y.x = u.y; m.z.x = u.z; m.w.x = u.w;
  m.x.y = v.x; m.y.y = v.y; m.z.y = v.z; m.w.y = v.w;
  m.x.z = n.x; m.y.z = n.y; m.z.z = n.z; m.w.z = n.w;
  m.x.w = p.x; m.y.w = p.y; m.z.w = p.z; m.w.w = p.w;

  mat4 m_t = mat4_trans(m);
  mat4 m_t_inv= mat4_inv(m_t);

  return m_t_inv;
}
```

I am currently trying to look at the top of a cube I made. The cube is 1x1x1 and is centered at the origin. I am setting the model_view like so:

```
vec4 e = {0, 1, 0, 1};
vec4 a = {0, 0, 0, 0};
vec4 u = {0, 0, 1, 0};
model_view = look_at(e, a, u);
```

I believe I have the parameters correct. I want to look down at the origin from y=1.
Does the issue appear to be in my function? or have I misunderstood the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth component of the axis vectors `u`, `v` and `p` has to be zero. In your case the fourth component of `vpn` is not zero, because `eye` is `{0, 1, 0, 1}`.
I recommend doing the computation of `u`, `v` and `p` with `vec3` rather than `vec4`. However, you can fix the issue with setting `vpn[3] = 0`:

```c
vec4 vpn = vec4_sub(eye, at);
vpn[3] = 0
```